# How to get only specific lines from web page content in Perl

Tags: perl

I am using below code to get web page content.  It's working fine, but I want to get specific lines out of that.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $content = get('http://www.w3schools.com/');
print $content;
my @arr;
my $flag = 0;
push (@arr, $content);
#print @arr;

my $find = "HTML 4.01";
for (@arr)
{
  if ($_ =~ /$find/) 
  {
    print "$_\n";
    print "passed\n";
    $flag = 1;
  }
}

if ($flag == 1)
{
  print "Testcase passed";
}
else
{  
  die "Testcases fails";
}
```

Comment: my $flag = $content =~ /$find/i;

Answer (score 1):

`get` fetches the whole content as a single value. If you want to process line-wise, [`split`](http://p3rl.org/split) first on [line endings](http://p3rl.org/rebackslash#%5cR).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple qw(get);

for my $line (split qr/\R/, get('http://www.w3schools.com/')) {
    print $line if $line =~ /\QHTML 4.01/;
}
```

Comment: user1583773, on Stack Overflow one says thanks by [▲ voting up](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) and [✔ accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answers.

Comment: Can anyone explain what split qr/\R/ is doing technically? What is qr?

Comment: @Memoc: qr// introduces a regular expression. See Regexp Quote-Like Operators in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop).